# Trying to cache Rails multi-page view with memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

I'm trying to understand why my Rails action caching isn't caching based on proper URL requests & params.

For example, when I request `page/2`, the cache system returns `page`.

This is a sample of the logs for the odd response:

```
Started GET "/clips/page/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-11 16:46:42 -0400
Processing by ClipsController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Cache read: views/localhost:3000/clips/page
Read fragment views/localhost:3000/clips/page (0.3ms)
  Rendered text template within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 50ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

What I think is strange is that clearly the URL being asked for is `/clips/page/2`, whereas the response is reading "fragment" `Read fragment views/localhost:3000/clips/page (0.3ms)`.

In my controller I have:

`caches_action :index, :layout => false`

and a very simple index action:

```
def index
    @clips = current_user.clips.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @clips }
    end
end
```

My development.rb config file, where I'm testing this has cachine enabled like so:

```
  # caching
  config.perform_caching = true # cache test
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true # cache test
  # config.action_controller.perform_caching = false # default

  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211'
```

I'm reading through this tutorial on caching: http://broadcastingadam.com/2012/07/advanced_caching_part_1-caching_strategies/

And the example there, almost identical to my situation gives the proper response:

```
Started GET "/posts/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-01 16:54:43 -0700
  Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Read fragment views/localhost:3000/posts/2 (0.5ms)
Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
Write fragment views/localhost:3000/posts/2 (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just tested a change to my routes, and realized that the problem was due to the way the routes asked for an **optional** page id!

So this will not work:

`get "/clips/page(/:page)", :controller => "clips", :action => "index"`

While this will work:

`get "/clips/page/:page", :controller => "clips", :action => "index"`